# How to expose MEX when I need the service to have NTLM authentication

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm developing a WCF service that is RESTful and SOAP, now both of them needs to be with NTLM authentication.

I also want to expose a MEX endpoint so that others can easily reference the service and work with it.

Now when I set IIS to require windows authentication I can use the REST service and make calls to the service succesfully, but when I want to reference the service with SVCUTIL it throws an error that it requires to be anonymous.

Here's my web.config:

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="214748563" maxBufferSize="214748563" maxBufferPoolSize="214748563">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm">

        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="214748563" maxBufferSize="214748563" maxBufferPoolSize="214748563">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm">

        </transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
  <mexHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mexHttpBinding"></binding>
  </mexHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint name="" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" helpEnabled="True">
    </standardEndpoint>
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
<services>
  <service name="Intel.ResourceScheduler.Service" behaviorConfiguration="Meta">
    <clear />
    <endpoint address="soap" name="SOAP" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Intel.ResourceScheduler.Service.IResourceSchedulerService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
    <endpoint address="" name="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="REST" contract="Intel.ResourceScheduler.Service.IResourceSchedulerService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" name="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="WCFBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>

  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Meta">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="REST">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="WCFBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the binding of the mex service, it will not work with mexHttpBinding because it has security disabled. I've not tested this in the exactly same scenario, but in my case I also had to change it because of the security.

In your example I would try changing it like this:

```
<endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"/>
```

To make the mex binding configuration more independent of the soap service binding configuration could also define and use a separate bindingConfiguration like

```
<binding name="secureMexHttpBinding" >
  <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm">
    </transport>
  </security>
</binding>
```

and then change the mex endpoint

```
endpoint address="mex" contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureMexHttpBinding"/>
```